# почему классовая компонента реакт реденрится 2 раза

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

  class List extends Component{
  
   render() {
    console.log("list")
    return (
      <div></div>
     )
   } 
  }
export default List
```

почему классовая рендериться 2раза а функциональные нет

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ErrorBoundry>
      <Context.Provider value={services}>
        <React.StrictMode>
          <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
      </Context.Provider>
    </ErrorBoundry>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Из за </React.StrictMode> убрал и все норма